# Is fnmatch.fnmatch incompatible to the Unix pattern filematching syntax?

Tags: python, fnmatch

I am using Python 3.7.6 and the [fnmatch.fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) function to match a filename with a given pattern. Most of my tests worked, but in specific the following example doesn't return the value as expected. Give is the following exanoke:

```
> fnmatch.fnmatch('_foo\bar.exe', '^_*')
False
```

What I try to do, to match any filename whose component starts with `_`. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What leads you to think that `^` matches leading characters in a *glob* expression, as opposed to a regex?

Comment: See the POSIX `fnmatch` spec at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html, and the glob syntax it includes by reference at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_02 -- `^` is not mentioned anywhere, outside the context of brace sequences.

Comment: Great, I wrote so much regex these days, that I didn't even think that this is not part of the specs! I would accept this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a place where Python fails to comply with the POSIX specification. UNIX pattern matching syntax does not require `^` to have any special meaning, *except* in a square-bracket character-set description.

See:

- [The POSIX specification for the `fnmatch` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html)
- [The POSIX specification for character sets](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_02)

---

This makes sense: Globs are implicitly anchored -- they *always* match only at the beginning, so there's no reason to support an explicit anchor.